# What issues can a client have running Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

My company recently deployed our first Silverlight app, and, as expected, we've had a couple of small issues with getting it to run on some clients' machines.  Mostly it was javascript that was disabled or using a non-supported browser, but I was wondering if there was a resource that lists the common issues that users run up against so that we can post in our FAQs section and hopefully decrease the volume of calls we recieve about it.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to add a link to the supported operating systems and browsers matrix: http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx#sysreq

Comment: If you're developing on the bleeding edge, it is possible that your customers may not have the exact version you used. Things are compatible, but some users may have to be prompted to update - and restricted permission users may be unable to do that. Its a short term thing, now that SL3 is out there, but beware IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user might not have Silverlight installed.

If the user doesn't have **administrator** permissions he or she cannot install it. -- FAIL!

The majority of users in corporate and government environments don't have administrator accounts.... to make sure they don't install stuff like silverlight. :-)